# Make a form that pulls choices from table in DB and then allows user to change to different foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a user model with the following columns:

```
username = models.CharField(db_column='Username',max_length=32,unique=True)
email = models.CharField(db_column='Email',max_length=255)
password = models.CharField(db_column='Password',max_length=128)
prosthodontist = models.ForeignKey('Prosthodontist',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

I'm trying to make a dropdown that allows the user to change their Prosthodontist value through django forms.  It can't be a static list cause it has to always have every available Prosthodontist as they get added.

Just for show this is what I have so far along the lines of the form:

```
class ChangeProsthodontistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('prosthodontist',)
    
    prosthodontist = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = "Prosthodontist",
        widget = forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'id':'prosthodontist',
            },
        ),
        choices=()
    )
```

Please help me with this cause I'm really confused I feel like I could be able to iterate through the entries with a for loop but I feel like there has to be a better way through Django.

Comment: Try using a model choice field that populates with the foreign key object:  `prosthodontist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Prosthodontist.objects.all())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer is `ModelChoiceField`.

```
prosthodontist = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    # ...
    queryset = Prosthodontist.objects.all(),
    # ...
)
```